# sed regular expression extraction

Tags: regex, bash, sed

i have a range of strings which conform to one of the two following patters:

`("string with spaces",4)`
or
`(string_without_spaces,4)`

I need to extract the "string" via a bash command, and so far have found a pattern that works for each, but not for both.

`echo "(\"string with spaces\",4)" | sed -n 's/("\(.*\)",.*)/\1/ip'`

output:`string with spaces`

`echo "(string_without_spaces,4)" | sed -n 's/(\(.*\),.*)/\1/ip'`

output:`string_without_spaces`

I have tried using `"\?` however it does not match the `"` if it is there:

`echo "(SIM,0)" | sed -n 's/("\?\(.*\)"\?,.*)/\1/ip'`

output: `SIM`

`echo "(\"SIM\",0)" | sed -n 's/("\?\(.*\)"\?,.*)/\1/ip'`

output: `SIM"`

can anyone suggest a pattern that would extract the string in both scenarios? I am not tied to sed but would prefer to not have to install perl in this environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `[^"]` instead of `.` to exclude `"` to be matched.

```
$ echo '("string with spaces",4)' | sed -n 's/("\?\([^"]*\)"\?,.*)/\1/p'
string with spaces
$ echo "(string_without_spaces,4)" | sed -n 's/("\?\([^"]*\)"\?,.*)/\1/p'
string_without_spaces

$ echo "(SIM,0)" | sed -n 's/("\?\([^"]*\)"\?,.*)/\1/p'
SIM
$ echo '("SIM",0)' | sed -n 's/("\?\([^"]*\)"\?,.*)/\1/p'
SIM
```